# Show tooltip on hover of custom marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following Google Map test: http://jsfiddle.net/gM6Z6/

As you can see it gets your position and then shows it on the map using three markers.

What I want to do is when a user hovers over any of the three markers, I want to show the following tooltip NEXT to the marker avatar:

```
var tooltipOptions={
    marker:marker,
    content: "You're here!",
    cssClass:'tooltip'
};
var tooltip = new Tooltip(tooltipOptions);
```

I'm not sure how to best do this, as I need this to work for all three markers, and be in the same position regardless of which marker was hovered. **It should ALWAYS appear next to the avatar like in the foursquare screenshot below BUT should move to the left or right dependant on the position of the icon on screen to allow it to fit.**

[image]

Can anyone help? As the docs are a little vague for my liking on this... I can create the tooltip but I'm confused how best to show it for all three markers but in the same position and viewport aware.

Comment: Why don't you make your marker big with a transparent background? (google knowing the size of your marker should make it fit) if your avatar is dynamic this probably won't work

Comment: Please update your fiddle to include your current Tooltip code. `Tooltip` isn't part of the API, and there is no indication of how it's implemented.

Answer (score 9):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/nickaknudson/KVa2d/

```
tooltip = new Tooltip("text");
...
tooltip.open(map, marker);
```

Customizable via CSS.

**UPDATE**

Commented code:
http://jsfiddle.net/nickaknudson/KVa2d/12/

**UPDATE 2**

Removed unnecessary bits:
http://jsfiddle.net/nickaknudson/KVa2d/14/

```
//========================
// Tooltip Class Definition
//   extends OverlayView:
//   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverlayView
//========================
var Tooltip
Tooltip = function(tip) {
    this.tip = tip;
    this.buildDOM();
};

$.extend(Tooltip.prototype, google.maps.OverlayView.prototype, {

    // build the DOM
    buildDOM: function() {
        // Body DIV
        this.bdiv = $("<div></div>").addClass('WindowBody').html(this.tip);
        // Window DIV
        this.wdiv = $("<div></div>").addClass('Window').append(this.bdiv);
        // Shadow DIV
        this.sdiv = $("<div></div>").addClass('WindowShadow');
        // Start Closed
        this.close();
    },

    // API - onAdd
    onAdd: function() {
        $(this.getPanes().floatPane).append(this.wdiv);
        $(this.getPanes().floatShadow).append(this.sdiv);
    },

    // API - onRemove
    onRemove: function() {
        this.wdiv.detach();
        this.sdiv.detach();

    },

    // API - draw
    draw: function() {
        var pos, left, top;
        // projection is accessible?
        if (!this.getProjection()) return;
        // position is accessible?
        if (!this.get('position')) return;
        // convert projection
        pos = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position'));
        // top offset
        top = pos.y - this.getAnchorHeight() / 2;
        // left offset
        if (this.getMap().getCenter().lng() > this.get('position').lng()) {
            left = pos.x + this.wdiv.width() * 0.5;
        } else {
            left = pos.x - this.wdiv.width() * 1.5;
        }
        // window position
        this.wdiv.css('top', top);
        this.wdiv.css('left', left);
        // shadow position
        this.sdiv.css('top', (top - this.getAnchorHeight() / 2));
        this.sdiv.css('left', left);
        // shadow size
        this.sdiv.width(this.wdiv.width());
        this.sdiv.height(this.wdiv.height());
    },

    // open Tooltip
    open: function(map, anchor) {
        // bind to map
        if (map) this.setMap(map);
        // bind to anchor
        if (anchor) {
            this.set('anchor', anchor);
            this.bindTo('anchorPoint', anchor);
            this.bindTo('position', anchor);
        }
        // need to force redraw otherwise it will decide to draw after we show the Tooltip                    
        this.draw();
        // show tooltip
        this.wdiv.show();
        this.sdiv.show();
        // set property
        this.isOpen = true;
    },

    // close Tooltip
    close: function() {
        // hide tooltip
        this.wdiv.hide();
        this.sdiv.hide();
        // set property
        this.isOpen = false;
    },

    // correctly get the anchorPoint height
    getAnchorHeight: function() {
        // See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow
        //   "The anchorPoint is the offset from the anchor's position to the tip of the InfoWindow."
        return -1 * this.get('anchorPoint').y;
    }
});
```

**UPDATE 3**

Better positioning using outerWidth() and outerHeight() to take borders etc into account. Removed shadow div.

http://jsfiddle.net/nickaknudson/KVa2d/16/​

```
//========================
// Tooltip Class Definition
//   extends OverlayView:
//   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverlayView
//========================
var Tooltip
Tooltip = function(tip) {
    this.tip = tip;
    this.buildDOM();
};

$.extend(Tooltip.prototype, google.maps.OverlayView.prototype, {

    // build the DOM
    buildDOM: function() {
        // Window DIV
        this.wdiv = $("<div></div>").addClass('Window').append(this.tip);
        // Start Closed
        this.close();
    },

    // API - onAdd
    onAdd: function() {
        $(this.getPanes().floatPane).append(this.wdiv);
    },

    // API - onRemove
    onRemove: function() {
        this.wdiv.detach();
    },

    // API - draw
    draw: function() {
        var pos, left, top;
        // projection is accessible?
        if (!this.getProjection()) return;
        // position is accessible?
        if (!this.get('position')) return;
        // convert projection
        pos = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position'));
        // top offset
        top = pos.y - this.getAnchorHeight() / 2 - this.wdiv.outerHeight()/2;
        // left offset
        if (this.getMap().getCenter().lng() > this.get('position').lng()) {
            left = pos.x + this.wdiv.outerWidth() * 0.3;
        } else {
            left = pos.x - this.wdiv.outerWidth() * 1.3;
        }
        // window position
        this.wdiv.css('top', top);
        this.wdiv.css('left', left);
    },

    // open Tooltip
    open: function(map, anchor) {
        // bind to map
        if (map) this.setMap(map);
        // bind to anchor
        if (anchor) {
            this.set('anchor', anchor);
            this.bindTo('anchorPoint', anchor);
            this.bindTo('position', anchor);
        }
        // need to force redraw otherwise it will decide to draw after we show the Tooltip                    
        this.draw();
        // show tooltip
        this.wdiv.show();
        // set property
        this.isOpen = true;
    },

    // close Tooltip
    close: function() {
        // hide tooltip
        this.wdiv.hide();
        // set property
        this.isOpen = false;
    },

    // correctly get the anchorPoint height
    getAnchorHeight: function() {
        // See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow
        //   "The anchorPoint is the offset from the anchor's position to the tip of the InfoWindow."
        return -1 * this.get('anchorPoint').y;
    }
});​
```

**RESOURCES**

- [modified from my GoogleMapsiPhoneWindow](https://github.com/nickaknudson/google-maps-window-iphone)

Comment: Quite a lot of code for something simple... Are you sure that's all necessary? Thanks for the code though. Would be interested to see if this can be simplified though. Cheers

Comment: Removed unnecessary code such as that generated by CoffeeScript. Could be even simpler if you don't desire a shadow effect?

Comment: Wasn't me who down voted you Nick. I'm personally very thankful for the help so far. So one last thing, can it be made so it's just a window and doesn't have a separate window and window body and no shadow? So effectively it's just one div that needs positioning on the screen for the tooltip? If you can do that then that'd be perfect and help me greatly in using it for a base.

Comment: Maybe you should try it yourself first and come back with your progress. This is not a place to get someone to do all the work for you.

Comment: I have done here: http://dev.driz.co.uk/GoogleMap.html but i'm not sure how to make it so only one div is being used (I'm currently only styling one div and i've removed the shadow) and also how to make sure that the tip is positioned as shown the original screenshot and not below as it appears be doing.

Comment: I picked up where you left off removing the shadow. Now only uses one div. Made the positioning a little more robust. http://jsfiddle.net/nickaknudson/KVa2d/16/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mouseover event to display your tooltip. (See events doc [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events)). You only need to show it for marker2 since it has the highest zIndex value.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'mouseout', function() {
});
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/chrish/BPr8d/) a jsFiddle displaying a tooltip using [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows). You don't have the tooltip code in your example. Can you update your example using the tooltip you created?

Comment: That's cool but I don't want to use the InfoWindow as it's over complicated for what I want here. All I want is to create a simple tooltip that I can then style up using CSS to look like what I show in the screenshot. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Yes that's why I've asked you to update the example with the tooltip you said you can create so that we can move forward

Comment: Hi, I never created one. All I did was write that code as I thought that's how it was done. In any case how would I create a simple tip that can be edited using CSS and is viewport aware. Cheers.